# My React function not working in production

Tags: reactjs

I have implemented a function called generateMapDispatchToProps that receives  multiple actionCreators objects and returns the same actionCreatos objects but with the name of the function changed to "dispatchActionCreators"

dispatch-actions.js

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

const generateMapDispatchToProps = (...actionCreators) =>
  actionCreators.reduce((mapDispatchToProps, actionCreator) => {
    const key = `dispatch${_.upperFirst(actionCreator.name)}`;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    mapDispatchToProps[key] = actionCreator;
    return mapDispatchToProps;
  }, {});

export {
  // todo: ignoring for now because more methods will be added
  // eslint-disable-next-line import/prefer-default-export
  generateMapDispatchToProps,
};
```

Countries.js

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = generateMapDispatchToProps(getCountries, clearCountries);
```

This function working in localhost but not in production. The localhost react version is 16.5.2

Comment: Hey Jose, do you get any errors on the console?

Comment: you have to define.. how it is not working.. what is expected and what is that you get ?

Comment: @go_diego the error say: **TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value).props.dispatchGetCities is not a function**

Comment: @Panther the function expects one or several actionsCreatores and returns the same actionsCreadores with the changed name of them, that is, if I pass getCountries, the function returns dispatchGetCountries. I did this because we are standardizing the code.

Comment: @JoséAlexanderZapataRuiz are you using create react app?

Comment: @go_diego well, I do not believe the project, but we are using yarn and bitbucket as a repository

Comment: With no other information, I'm wondering if there is something different in the way you build your development code compared to how you build your production code.

Comment: @go_diego The code is the same, once it passes the tests, it goes into production. It seems super weird, maybe something I'm letting go or maybe some configuration

Comment: So the same configuration is used to build the code fro development and production?